# removing an xml from a big xml via replace function

Tags: string, replace, xslt-2.0

I Have a big xml, out of that xml I need to remove another small xml. I am using the replace function but no joys.

Big xml:

```
<Records>
<Row>
    <AA>26-JUL-2017</AA>
    <BB>21</BB>
    <CC>30-JUL-2017</CC>
</Row>
<Row>
    <AA>29-JUL-2017</AA>
    <BB>22</BB>
    <CC>30-JUL-2017</CC>
</Row>
</Records>
```

Small XML:

```
<Records>
<Row>
    <AA>26-JUL-2017</AA>
    <BB>21</BB>
    <CC>30-JUL-2017</CC>
</Row>
</Records>
```

Output I need:

```
<Records>
<Row>
    <AA>29-JUL-2017</AA>
    <BB>22</BB>
    <CC>30-JUL-2017</CC>
</Row>
</Records>
```

The xslt function I am trying to use is:

```
<xsl:variable name="Out">

                <xsl:copy-of select="replace($Old, $New, '')" />

        </xsl:variable>
```

Here the Variable Old contains the big xml and the variable New contains the small xml.
But I dont get the xml tags only values. Even though I use COPY-OF.

Comment: Updated the section thanks

Comment: replace() expects a string. If you give it a node, it atomizes the node, which in effect loses all structural markup. It's not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity transformation (e.g. in XSLT 3.0 simply `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` or in XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

) plus an empty template `<xsl:template match="Records/Row[some $row in $New//Row satisfies deep-equal(., $row)]"/>` (where I assume you have e.g. `<xsl:param name="New" select="doc('small.xml')"/>`). The `replace` function is for working with plain strings.